Encrypting a spec file created by pyinstaller
I'm trying to encrypt my project. I need to make an executable file by using pyinstaller and then ı tried to encrypt the file with coding on .spec file. I'm thinking using tinyAES but I don't know how.
Is it possible encrypting the file by changing the .spec file?
Can I use tinyAES?
I tried nuitka but it creates problems with pyqt5 which i used in my project.
